# Not able to configure change object notification for php application in google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gsutil

I am getting the following error when I try to setup notification using gsutil command:

gsutil notification watchbucket https://APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/cron gs://bucket

```
Watching bucket gs://APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/ with application URL https://APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/cron ...

Watch bucket attempt failed:
  AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden

You attempted to watch a bucket with an application URL of:

  https://APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/cron

which is not authorized for your project. Please ensure that you are using
Service Account authentication and that the Service Account's project is
authorized for the application URL. Notification endpoint URLs must also be
whitelisted in your Cloud Console project. To do that, the domain must also be
verified using Google Webmaster Tools. For instructions, please see:

  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization

AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
```

I have followed all the steps from the url below for Notification Authorization:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

But I am still getting the above error. What step am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue myself. I had missed "https://" while adding the domain name.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this. I am hitting the same issue. I added the domain to the domain verification section with `https://app-name.appspot.com` and verified ownership in webmaster central which also has `https://app-name.appspot.com`

Comment: Hi, I followed all the steps mentioned under the url:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification
Specifically, please go through the following steps:
1. Creating a Service Account

2. Configuring gsutil to Use the Service Account

3. Identifying a Domain to Receive Notifications

Once your service account is authorized, you can execute commands to watch bucket and stop channel.

gsutil notification watchbucket <url>
gsutil notification stopchannel <channel-id>

Following the steps mentioned above will actually configure object notification for you.
Thanks

Comment: thank you :) it turns out I didn't add the correct service account to my bucket.